# Recording video on 4K produces weird sounds

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, video

I’ve an iPhone 11 Pro that never gave any problem. Currently using iOS 14.2. Yesterday I recorded a video, using 4K and 60fps, and the result was this: (please be advised, loud and annoying audio on it) https://photos.app.goo.gl/BWbC6KEWQoqpaFPf6

I tried to reproduce the issue with no luck. All videos I did after this one (using the same settings) have the usual, correct sound.

At the time of recording it was not specially windy, Bluetooth was deactivated and airplane mode was turned on.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The sound is known as [Motorboating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorboating_\(electronics\)) & is a known issue in microphone/amplifier circuitry. However, that I recognise it & know its name… unfortunately doesn't mean I know what caused it or how to fix it :\ I've known it happen in microphones that have been allowed to get damp.

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin, thanks a lot for the quick reply. Had no idea this sound might even have a Wikipedia page. I'll contact the seller as it's still under warranty, and see what they offer.